# Webscraping: How to execute the function behind a button without browser emulation?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I do my first steps in webscraping using python selene and the browser inspector. I use the webdriver object to fill some textboxes and click on a button.
The input of the textboxes are passed over to the function that is called by the button. That works fine but before clicking the button
the code has to wait a few seconds, otherwise the request is not executed when clicking the button. Now, instead of emulating a browser, 
I would like to call the function that is executed on button click directly and pass over the arguments without filling the textboxes.
I assume this is going to be faster than emulating the browser.

This is the html code behind the button:

```
<button class="btn btn--submit mb--xs" data-set-icmp="iup:check"
name="submit-0" data-ng-disabled="abc.$wait"
data-ng-click="abc.check({ vpVar: v.vpVar });">
            Check </button>
```

I assume v.vpVar contains the input of the textboxes and I have to call "abc.check({ vpVar: v.vpVar })" in some kind of way.
Is there a way to find out what v.vpVar looks like? Maybe something like variable monitoring in a browser?
How would I call "abc.check({ vpVar: v.vpVar })" in python selene?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# selene 2.0.0b5
from selene import be
from selene.shared.support import browser


browser.element("button[data-ng-click='abc.check({ vpVar: v.vpVar });']").should(be.visible)
```